# jQuery $.get doesn't work for "local" files in Phonegap or Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mobile-safari

I have a templating system I was trying to use with my Phonegap App that utilizes jQuery and the $.get() function.

`$.get('templates/' + name + '.html', someFunctionHere(){});`

When I run the app as a server on localhost and view it through Chrome or Safari the templating system works perfectly.
When I run the app through Phonegap on the iOS Simulator, it doesn't work.  No file is returned and "someFunctionHere()" doesn't run.
Important note:  When I use Mobile Safari under the iOS Simulator to view the page served by my localhost it also does not work.

To me, this sounds like the WebKit browser that Mobile Safari and Phonegap use won't allow access to local files?  This feels completely incorrect but that's how it looks.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, or know of a way to get around it?

Comment: You usually  can't `.ajax` files from the local filesystem (`.get` is just a shortcut to `.ajax`). It has to point to a webserver of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think safari does not support async call which is on by default and you need to turn off async mode in order to get it worked in safari.

Comment: Should point out for the answer, I had to switch to using $.ajax and manually specify `async:false` in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Instead of using localhost access the files from the file:// protocol and it should work, it's a cross domain restriction in Safari / Mobile Safari.

Comment: That would require knowing the file:// location across multiple platforms (we are targetting iOS, Android and Blackberry).  There has to be a better way to do it than that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the type parameter of $.get to 'text'? That worked for me. If you don't $.get will try to guess it and in my case it guessed it wrong.